# GWT RequestContext ENum in the request

Tags: gwt, enums, requestcontext

If we use enum as one of the attribute in the Request invocation , it throws an UnsupportedOpeationException and does not even invoke the service method on the server.

```
@Service(value = DesignService.class, locator = DesignServiceLocator.class)
public interface DesignRequest extends RequestContext {
    Request<List<DesignProxy>> findDesign(SortEnum sortorder);
}
```

when we invoke the designRequest.findDesign(sortorderEnum).fire() the UnsupportOperationException is thrown on the javascript console on chrome dev tools/Firebug console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is related to [Issue 6504](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6504), which will throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` if it fails to find the type you are using - consider trying to change to class methods in your enum, or wait until 2.4 is released.

If you are not using anonymous enum instances, can you post more info about this error, such as where the exception is thrown from?